# How are views dynamically added with the Router?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm trying to dynamically generate views inside a loop, and match each one to the route of a Router.

The code below is inside a for loop, which loops recursively through a JSON file and adds a route to the Router for each JSON node which has child nodes. It is for a tile based navigation app I'm writing which has tiered screens containing tiles.

```
var oView = new sap.ui.core.mvc.View(aData[i].id+"id", {viewName: aData[i].id});

oRouter.addRoute({
  name: aData[i].id,
  pattern: sPattern,
  view: oView.getViewName(),
  viewLevel : iViewLevel,
  viewPath: ???
});
oRouter.setView(oView.getViewName(), oView);
```

How do I set the viewPath etc, when I don't have a physical file? Since the errors I get indicate the app is looking for e.g. tile1.view.js, tile2.view.js?

Comment: Interesting approach... Taking a step back, why would you create your views completely dynamic? Why not have a physical container view which you can call, and have its content then generated dynamically? That way you can still use the viewPath

Comment: That sounds like a better way of doing it. :) I'll try that. Is there any good reason for creating views dynamically, though?

Comment: Dynamically created content, absolutely. Dynamically created views, I have yet to come across the first use case though...